whats the actual default password to connect to WU-1b
I can see the Nikon WU-1b wifi but it is asking me for password.  I forgot what is it.  How do I reset it?  or whats the default password

Have you read the manual and followed the steps there? It seems that you connect using the WPS standard.

Is this question a duplicate? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85722/how-to-reset-the-password-on-a-nikon-wu-1a-wifi-adapter

Resetting the device is unlikely to work.
Connect the wu-1b to a Windows machine over wps (press the button on the wu-1b until it flashes red and green), after it is connected go to the wireless adapter settings; check and note your wireless key. Now insert it on your phone/WMU app and you should be able to connect the wu-1b.
